# Jquery Slider Images loading

Tags: image, slider

http://ftp8.org/article_10-selfies-taken-moments-before-death-1

Please take a view on the Gallery click next buttons. Somethimes only gray image is visible and if you scroll down it will show up !

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related with lazyload plugin; it removes the correct image source path. 
Try to disable it or paste this code into window load function.

```
$('img.lazy').each(function(){ var data = $(this).attr('data-original'); $(this).attr('src',data) })
```

Please let me know, did it solve the issue or not.

Comment: I've just added the code into console in my chrome dev.tools and seems like it works. Did you try to wrap it into window on load function? try this please: 
$(window).bind('load', function(){ $('img.lazy').each(function(){ var data = $(this).attr('data-original'); $(this).attr('src',data) }) })